# Need Help understanding particular define directive in C

Tags: c, syntax, macros, c-preprocessor

I am a CS student and I am learning C. I have an assignment in which our instructor gave us a .h and two .c files that have code segments that require us to complete to make functions work.

In the header file he has the following #define statements:

```
# ifndef LT
# define LT(A, B) ((A) < (B))
# endif

# ifndef EQ
# define EQ(A, B) ((A) == (B))
# endif
```

for the first define, I know that LT is the "name" but I dont understand what the syntax to the right is doing. Same with the second.

It appears to me that LT is the comparison of two variables A and B and it check that A is greater then B.

Would someone please help me to understand this

Comment: **HInt**: **l**ess **t**han and **eq**uals.

Comment: Those are called macros. So start by reading the manual. If you are using gcc the relevant section is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html).

Comment: LT checks that A is Less Than  B (not the other way round)

Comment: Most compilers will have an option to stop after preprocessing, and output that code. Do that for some very simple code using these macros and see what they expand to.

Comment: You are asking a very fundamental question on how C proprocessors work. That's better learnt through a text book than through a QA site like stackoverflow.com.

Comment: In a macro definition, if the macro name is immediately followed by `(`, it takes arguments (this is called a *function-like macro*). The arguments to `LT` are named `A` and `B`.

Comment: @kaylum, thanks for the link to the manual. I must have been using bad terminology, because this had all the info I wanted, and I didn't come across it in my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are macros.

If you have in your c code

```
if(LT(xx, yy))
{
   printf("xx is less than yy\n");
}
```

then at compile time the code is changed to

```
if((xx) < (yy))
{
   printf("xx is less than yy\n");
}
```

this is done by the preprocessor changing #defined things that it sees to their contents

Comment: Yes, and if you are using gcc you could also use `cpp` to see the preprocessed file...

Comment: Thank you! SO this is just a macro basically. When I type LT( 54, 63) in my code it will be replaced with ((54) < (63)) when I compile the program.

Comment: yes, and if you didnt know that then you have a terrible teacher :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to get a book about C and read upon the preprocessor functionalities. It is merely a syntactic replacement without semantic meaning.

The first can be read like this:
If `LT` is not defined then introduce the preprocessor definition `LT`.
From that point of definition on wherever the preprocessor finds the text (I don't say string on purpose here to make a point) `LT` with two parameters, let's say `text1` and `text2`, then this text `LT(text1, text2)` will be replaced by the `((text1) < (text2))`.

Same for the second.

Note the parentheses, they are important. Make an example of the following appearance in your code `LT(x+y, z-1)` and you should understand why parentheses are important here.

I can recommend K&R for learning C. It has a chapter dedicated to the preprocessor and not difficult to understand.
The more you learn you'll notice that my terminology is not the best here, but for the moment try to grasp that concept.

Comment: Thank you Elyasin. So, this is defining how to output whatever is put in parenthesis following the LT or EQ. This will not do a comparison, it will format the out put based on what is entered as "parameters" and this is how the compiler will read LT?

Comment: It simply replaces LT and it's parameters by the definition, that's all. That's preprocessing. Once preprocessing finished, the replaced definition must be meaningful to the C compiler.